# Problems with div floating

Tags: html, css

Hello Stackoverflow community, ive got question about positioning my div. When i double click td, div appears, but if that td is near right side, my div goes out of width, is it possible somehow to change floating from right side of mouse to left side? Here is the picture. Thats how it looks like if i want to change date which is in the right corner:

[image]

As you can seee:

[image]

How can i fix this to fit in window no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a floating div, it's absolutely positioned.

The problem is that `left: 1094px` rule you have. Change it to `right: 0px` and experiment with the number that works the best.

If you want to lock it on the right edge of the parent element, make sure you put `position: relative` to the parent element.

Comment: I know that my div is out of width size because of left: 1094px, but it is mouse position. I want that div would somehow stay in window, is there are any possible stuff?

Comment: Oh I see, why don't you subtract the element width from the mouse position then? In that case, the mouse will be touching the right edge of the element